# What is the difference between PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager and PoolingClientConnectionManager

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

What is the difference between **PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager** and **PoolingClientConnectionManager**. Why PoolingClientConnectionManager got deprecated? What is the drawback in that class?

Comment: Looks like a regular API change. Library API can change from version to version, so API vendors mark old stuff as deprecated. They can't just delete it, because it will break the client code. Deprecation keeps backwards compatibility and forces users to use new API. You can ty to find details in javadocs or Apache HTTP client changelog.

Answer (score 1):

I also couldn't find any precise references in the documentation, nor in JIRA. However, there is a more authoritative source. According to the original [git commit](https://apache.googlesource.com/httpclient/+/78856ca1b1a950c677c7a09d139e8f8c7b66e30f) from 4 November 2012 where the new class was added:

> Connection management API redesign: deprecated
>   ClientConnectionManager, ManagedClientConnection,
>   OperatedClientConnection and ClientConnectionOperator in favor of a
>   simpler **HttpClientConnectionManager** interface. The new API has a much
>   smaller footprint and no longer supports the concept of managed or
>   operated connections. Internal connection mangement (sic) logic is no longer
>   exposed to the consumer

So unless you need managed or operated connections, or to access internal connection management, you should just update to use the new name(s).

Besides which, this was released in version [4.3](https://hc.apache.org/news.html) from September 2013, and we're now up to 4.5.2, so clearly this has stood the test of time.